# Doesn't Retrieve the Value of Uploaded File Using Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Goal:
I would like to have the second input name "file2" to be uploaded automatically to the actionresult with support of the jquery code using the latest version of FF, CHrome and IE.

Problem:
It doesn't work because HttpPostedFileBase file2 is null. it is supposed to be contain any value based on uploaded file with support of jquery.

Info:
*It would be great that it would be working for IE, Chrome and FF.
*There is a purpose why I'm asking about this unusual approach.
*The sourcecode of jquery and html work only for FF.

Thank you!

```js
$("#file1id").change(function () {
  if($('#file2id').length){
    $('#file2id').remove();
  }
  
  
  $(this).clone().attr('id', 'file2id').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file1id" name="file" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />

<input id="file2id" name="file2" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />
```

```
public ActionResult UploadShipments(HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpPostedFileBase file2)
{


---
}
```

---

```
<input id="file1id" name="file" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />

<input id="file2id" name="file2" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />
```

---

```
$("#file1id").change(function () {
  if($('#file2id').length){
     $('#file2id').remove();
  }


  $(this).clone().attr('id', 'file2id').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

---

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ayd4x079/2/
```

Comment: *uploaded automatically* can you define it? Is it something on file selection just upload the file?

Comment: Yes, it is a file (.txt or .xml) that is selected for uploading to the backend

Comment: _uploaded automatically can you define it?_ this doesn't define it.

Comment: In this context when you select a file for id file1id, a copy of the file1id same be same to the id='file2id' and then when you press on the upload button, you upload them (file1id, file2id) to the backend by selecting one file only. That is how I define uploaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript code working, try to use `Request.Files` object. It contains all the files that is server recieved from client

Answer (score 0):

```
 var fileInput = document.getElementById('id-input-file-2');

            var ext = fileInput.files[0].name.substring(fileInput.files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.'));
            if (ext.toLowerCase() == ".docx") {
                var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;
                formdata.append(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0]);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '@Url.Action("uploadDocument", "Transcription")' + "?jobid=" + job_id + "&transid=" + trans_id);
                xhr.send(formdata);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {...
```

in controller

```
 public ActionResult uploadDocument(string jobid, string transid)
    {
            int count = Request.Files.Count;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                var name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            }
```

u will get every information about uploaded file in controller